# How do you return the predicted dataset of simple linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I have a linear regression (shown polyfit but only to 1 degree to keep linear) and I am trying to return a dataset of all predicted results from 11 months to 20 months. Currently I have 10 months of data and print(speed) would print the result at the 20th month.

```
import numpy
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 4, 3, 9, 8, 3, 7, 10, 8, 20]

mymodel = numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1))

speed = mymodel(20)
print(speed)
```

Desired results (rounded)

```
import pandas as pd
df_results=pd.DataFrame({'months(x)':[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 'amount(y)':[15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27]}) 
df_results
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get prediction from 11th month to 20th month.

This snippet should give you the expected result.

```py
import numpy
import pandas as pd

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = [1, 4, 3, 9, 8, 3, 7, 10, 8, 20]

mymodel = numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1))

speed = mymodel(20)
print(speed)

input_data_from_11_months_to_20_months = numpy.arange(11, 21, 1)

prediction_from_11_months_to_20_months = numpy.round(
    mymodel(input_data_from_11_months_to_20_months)
)

print(prediction_from_11_months_to_20_months)


df_results = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "months(x)": input_data_from_11_months_to_20_months,
        "amount(y)": prediction_from_11_months_to_20_months,
    }
)

print(df_results.head())

# Output
"""
26.89696969696969
[15. 16. 17. 19. 20. 21. 23. 24. 26. 27.]
   months(x)  amount(y)
0         11       15.0
1         12       16.0
2         13       17.0
3         14       19.0
4         15       20.0
"""
```

I used `numpy` `round` function to round the values and used the fitted model to get the prediction. `numpy` `arange` function creates the input months from 11th to 20th where step size is 1.